# Which is more correct: "preferred that he do" or "preferred him to do"?

Tags: formality, subjunctive-mood, subordinate-clauses, register, mandative-subjunctive

I would like to know which form of this question is “more correct” than the other:

1. What would you have preferred (that) he do?
2. What would you have preferred him to do?

Comment: Pity there isn't a "useful" flag for the “**marked** as duplicate” like there is for comments(!)

Comment: "Somehow, she preferred that to the thaumaturge’s gleeful amusement."

Answer (score 0):

The first, although we could argue all day about what does and doesn't fit.

The second looks odd because *him* is for objects, and the *he* you're talking about isn't the object here, your preferred action (by him) is the object of *preferred*. So *him to do* should be ***that he do***.

Comment: There’s nothing odd about _him_ in this context. Compare “What would you have liked him to do?”, which is exactly parallel, apart from the fact that the infinitive with its oblique subject sounds perfectly natural with _like_, but jarring with _prefer_.

Comment: It jars a lot. Case where **him** works: *I **require him** to do [X]* (which could also be *I **require that he** do [X]*), versus *I **mandate that he** do [X]* (which cannot work with **him** as as we’re mandating the action, not the person). Saying *I prefer **him** to do [X]* is the answer to *Which of those people would you prefer [to] do [X]?*

Comment: I agree that it jars and doesn’t work. It’s only the reasoning in your last paragraph that I disagree with: the reason that it doesn’t work isn’t that _him_ is not the object, because it works fine in other parallel constructions where _him_ is also not the object. Syntactically, _him_ is the subject of the infinitive _to do_ (the trace postcedent of _what_ is its object), and _him to do [what]_ is the object of _preferred_; but this in itself does not explain why it works with some verbs and not with others. I’m afraid the answer is just that it’s a property of the individual verb.

Comment: It *is* related to which verb is in use, but I suggest it's a fundamental part of  the meaning of the verb, whether it applies directly to the *person* involved. So I assert that *prefer* works like *mandate* (but softer!), not like *require*, in relating to the *doing* not the *doer*. You can leave the *that* out of *that he do*, leaving *I prefer he do ...*. I have to concede a lot of people do say or write *him* in places like this. With *require*, you are requiring the action *of* the person... I've reached my depth here! Would you say the *him* is genetive or ablative?